# iOS GPS Location without carrier service neither wifi connection

Tags: iphone, geolocation, wifi, carrier

specifically this question is for iPhone only, basically the question is - does iOS location service still give the geo-location (lat, long) when the device has no carrier service neither wifi connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will give you the location using GPS and if the GPS signal is not there it still gives you the old cached location. So in any case it will give you the location.

Comment: Just to be clear, the old cached location could very well be worthless depending on when it was last updated.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem... but you can check it's time stamp and ignore old location but in that case if network/Wi-Fi is not available GPS might not be able to calculate location when you are inside a building or some thing similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, the latest models (since 3? I think?) have an actual GPS so as long as you can "see" open sky it will be getting lat/long.  Whether or not the related apps are able to function (whether it can load the maps, for instance) is another matter entirely.